Calculate joint PDF of vector transformation
Given joint PDF of 2 random variables X and Y:
$$
\begin{equation}
f(x, y)=
    \begin{cases}
        4xy{e}^{-(x^2 + y^2)} & \text{for } x,y \ge 0, \\
        0 & \text{otherwise. }
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
Calculate joint PDF of $\left(U = XY, V = \frac{X}{Y}\right)$.
I know the result is $\frac{2u}{v}{e}^{-u(v + \frac{1}{v})}$, just don't know how to calculate it.
My approach was to find CDF, then calculate density as derivative of this function:
$F(u, v) = \mathbb{P}(U \le u, V \le v) = \mathbb{P}(XY \le u, \frac{X}{Y} \le v) = \mathbb{P}(X \le \frac{u}{Y}, X \le vY)$.
I've tried the approach to divide this into 2 double integrals where inside integral of variable $x$ goes from $0$ to $vy$ plus another integral where integral of variable goes from $0$ to $\frac{u}{y}$, but got different result. Outside integral of variable y goes from $0$ to $\infty$. But this approach was not right as I got different result.
Thanks.

You can use transformation of random variables

@MathLearner you probably mean calculate PDF of U and V separately, but issue is that U and V might not and actually are not independent, so I cannot just calculate them separately and then have joint density as their product. Or you meant something else I did not understood?

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R^2}, g(x, y) = (xy, \frac{x}{y})$ ($g$ in particular is a measurable function).

Then, if we denote $u := xy, v := \frac{x}{y}$, we obtain $x = \sqrt{uv}$ and $y = \sqrt{\frac{u}{v}}$. So, $g^{-1}(u,v) = (\sqrt{uv}, \sqrt{\frac{u}{v}})$, and determinant of the jacobian of the transformation would be
$$J_{g^{-1}} = \begin{vmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{v}{u}} & \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{u}{v}} \\ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{uv}} & -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{u}{v}}\end{vmatrix} = \frac{-1}{2v}.$$
So, $f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(g^{-1}(u,v))|J_g^{-1}| = f_{X,Y}(\sqrt{uv}, \sqrt{\frac{u}{v}})\frac{1}{2v}=\frac{2u}{v}e^{-u(v+\frac{1}{v})}$.

You can see this and this for further references and examples about random variables transformations.

Got it, thanks!
